# python multiple text file with different delimeter

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple files with different delimiters (| , ). I need to use different seperater in read_cvs function. Is that possible or I need to convert the delimiter to one (line comma) and then use sep = ','?

```
import glob
path =r'C:\Users\hadadir\Desktop\temp' # use your path
all_Files = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")
frame = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, sep=",|", header = None , nrows=2) for f in all_Files))
df

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0   3130A0|QE|39104|2000|20140630|0|17306|2000  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   3130A0|QY|39104|0|20140630|-1000|17306|1000 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
0   "3135G0"    "XC"    "39104" 1000    20130630    1000    "17306" 1000
1   "3136FP"    "DY"    "39104" 2000    20130630    0   "17306" 2000
```

for converting:

```
import glob
path =r'C:\Users\hadadir\Desktop\temp' # use your path
all_Files = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")
frame = pd.DataFrame()
```

results:

```
C:\Users\hadadir\Desktop\temp\HOLDINGQ2.TXTC:\Users\hadadir\Desktop\temp\HOLDING_20131224.txt
```

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: The second solution (based on converting each text file, first) returns the paths concatenated. Please see the results at the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.read_csv` generally treats multiple-character delimiters as a regular expression ([documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)).  Therefore, you can use a set syntax (like `sep="[\|,]"`) to indicate multiple delimiters.